# Fields nullable in the database but force users to type them in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

How can I implement the following Scenario:
I would like to have a signup wizard that creates the `userProfile` account. In that form I have a `companyName` (required). I will then take that `companyName` and start a record in the `companyInfromation` Table. All of the columns in this table should be nullable since I am starting the record on user signup.

After the user signs up they are prompted that they are required to finish filling out the company information, so they are taken to the company information form.

now here is my question, how can I make this form have required attributes and make the user fill out all of the required information? (Not just JavaScript but also modelState validation) I thought about a viewModel but I'm getting a bunch of "cannot convert the type 'project.model.companyinformation' to project.model.companyinformationviewmodel'" error.

I'm very new to C#, asp.net MVC. I used to just take the easy way out and use vb.net and asp.net webforms.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Jquery would be an easy solution. Why do you need js and model state validation both??

Comment: @kandroid. JS validation can be easily disabled by the user. You should always have server side validation in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a model is the correct approach. You can't cast from entity to model. You need to transfer the data yourself.

```
var entity = GetEntity();
var model = new MyModelType();
model.ID = entity.ID;
model.OtherField = entity.OtherField;
```

There's a useful project called [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) that can automate this for you.

An alternative approach is to create a custom validation attribute `RequiredIf`. This would validate if a specified boolean field has a value of true:

```
public class MyModelType
{
    [NotMapped]
    private bool _enableFullValidation;

    [RequiredIf("_enableFullValidation")]
    public string MyNoneRequiredDBField { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for clearing that up for me. Which method would you choose? Custom requiredif or the model mapping?

Comment: It depends on your application. Personally, I don't like my entities anywhere near my view. I always use a special mode. Having entities as models means your UI has to match your DB or you need a lot of transformation logic in your view. Also, RequiredIf style validation is handy if you want to have say a dependency field (e.g. `Where did you hear about us?:[Other]`* - `Please Explain[___]`*) but I wouldn't dirty your entities with it unless its quicker and cleaner for you to do so.